# What does no anticipation following Athey, 2021?

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

From a paper of [Athey, 2021, Journal of Econometrics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407621000488), I saw the assumption of no anticipation effect is Assumption 2:

> For all units *i*, all time periods *t* , and for all adoption dates
> $\alpha$ , such that $\alpha$ *> t*,
>
> $y_{it}$($\alpha$) = $y_{it}$ ($\propto$)

I am wondering how to understand the equation above intuitively?
I think "**no anticipation effect**" should be testing the placebo effect before the actual event date. But in this case, **it seems that they concern the after-event observations, which is quite counter-intuitive to my limited understanding**.